# Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland"

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, qt, wayland, sway

I get the following error when I run vlc:

```
$ vlc
VLC media player 3.0.11 Vetinari (revision 3.0.11-0-gdc0c5ced72)
[0000561d2cc24a30] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
[0000561d2cbf2f50] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[0000561d2cb5a460] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[0000561d2cb5a460] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

I have installed vlc using `pacman` in Arch Linux.  I am trying to run vlc in `sway` which is a `wayland` window manager.

Running vlc after setting any of the following environment variables, leads to the same error.

```
$ QT_QPT_PLATFORM=wayland vlc
$ QT_QPT_PLATFORM=offscreen vlc
$ QT_PLUGIN_PATH=/usr/lib/qt/plugins/ vlc
```

Also, uninstalling vlc and reinstalling it using `pacman` (which uninstalls and reinstalls `qt`) didn't resolve the issue; same error persists.

Here is the output of running vlc with the QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS flag on.

```
$ QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1 vlc
VLC media player 3.0.11 Vetinari (revision 3.0.11-0-gdc0c5ced72)
[000055b67a7aea30] vlcpulse audio output error: PulseAudio server connection failure: Connection refused
[000055b67a847f60] main interface error: no suitable interface module
[000055b67a6e4460] main libvlc error: interface "globalhotkeys,none" initialization failed
[000055b67a6e4460] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/usr/bin/platforms" ...
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not find the Qt platform plugin "wayland" in ""
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

And here is the output of `ldd /usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so` which implies all dependencies are installed.

```
$ ldd /usr/lib/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc2cbdc000)
    libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5XcbQpa.so.5 (0x00007faa3c086000)
    libQt5Gui.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5 (0x00007faa3b9b3000)
    libQt5Core.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5Core.so.5 (0x00007faa3b461000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007faa3b284000)
    libc.so.6 => /usr/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007faa3b0bd000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /usr/lib/libfontconfig.so.1 (0x00007faa3b072000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x00007faa3af9c000)
    libQt5DBus.so.5 => /usr/lib/libQt5DBus.so.5 (0x00007faa3af16000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007faa3aef4000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0x00007faa3aeef000)
    libxcb-icccm.so.4 => /usr/lib/libxcb-icccm.so.4 (0x00007faa3aee9000)
    libxcb-image.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-image.so.0 (0x00007faa3aee3000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0x00007faa3aedc000)
    libxcb-keysyms.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb-keysyms.so.1 (0x00007faa3aed7000)
    libxcb-randr.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-randr.so.0 (0x00007faa3aec5000)
    libxcb-render-util.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-render-util.so.0 (0x00007faa3aebf000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-render.so.0 (0x00007faa3aeaf000)
    libxcb-shape.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0x00007faa3aeaa000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0x00007faa3ae9e000)
    libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0x00007faa3ae94000)
    libxcb-xinerama.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-xinerama.so.0 (0x00007faa3ae8f000)
    libxcb-xkb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb-xkb.so.1 (0x00007faa3ae71000)
    libxcb-xinput.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxcb-xinput.so.0 (0x00007faa3ae4c000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1 (0x00007faa3ae22000)
    libX11.so.6 => /usr/lib/libX11.so.6 (0x00007faa3acdf000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/libSM.so.6 (0x00007faa3acd5000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/libICE.so.6 (0x00007faa3acb8000)
    libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxkbcommon-x11.so.0 (0x00007faa3acae000)
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => /usr/lib/libxkbcommon.so.0 (0x00007faa3ac6d000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0x00007faa3ab44000)
    libm.so.6 => /usr/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007faa3a9fd000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007faa3a9e3000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGL.so.1 (0x00007faa3a95d000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /usr/lib/libpng16.so.16 (0x00007faa3a923000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x00007faa3a909000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /usr/lib/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0x00007faa3a83a000)
    libmd4c.so.0 => /usr/lib/libmd4c.so.0 (0x00007faa3a822000)
    libsystemd.so.0 => /usr/lib/libsystemd.so.0 (0x00007faa3a777000)
    libdouble-conversion.so.3 => /usr/lib/libdouble-conversion.so.3 (0x00007faa3a760000)
    libicui18n.so.67 => /usr/lib/libicui18n.so.67 (0x00007faa3a460000)
    libicuuc.so.67 => /usr/lib/libicuuc.so.67 (0x00007faa3a279000)
    libdl.so.2 => /usr/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007faa3a273000)
    libpcre2-16.so.0 => /usr/lib/libpcre2-16.so.0 (0x00007faa3a1e6000)
    libzstd.so.1 => /usr/lib/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007faa3a114000)
    /usr/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007faa3c1d8000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /usr/lib/libexpat.so.1 (0x00007faa3a0e4000)
    libbz2.so.1.0 => /usr/lib/libbz2.so.1.0 (0x00007faa3a0d1000)
    libdbus-1.so.3 => /usr/lib/libdbus-1.so.3 (0x00007faa3a07c000)
    libxcb-util.so.1 => /usr/lib/libxcb-util.so.1 (0x00007faa3a072000)
    libXau.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXau.so.6 (0x00007faa3a06d000)
    libXdmcp.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6 (0x00007faa3a065000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /usr/lib/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007faa3a05c000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /usr/lib/libpcre.so.1 (0x00007faa39fea000)
    libGLdispatch.so.0 => /usr/lib/libGLdispatch.so.0 (0x00007faa39f31000)
    libGLX.so.0 => /usr/lib/libGLX.so.0 (0x00007faa39efe000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /usr/lib/libgraphite2.so.3 (0x00007faa39ed9000)
    librt.so.1 => /usr/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007faa39ece000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /usr/lib/liblzma.so.5 (0x00007faa39ea6000)
    liblz4.so.1 => /usr/lib/liblz4.so.1 (0x00007faa39e84000)
    libgcrypt.so.20 => /usr/lib/libgcrypt.so.20 (0x00007faa39d61000)
    libicudata.so.67 => /usr/lib/libicudata.so.67 (0x00007faa3824a000)
    libgpg-error.so.0 => /usr/lib/libgpg-error.so.0 (0x00007faa38223000)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try installing the package `qt5-wayland` if it not already installed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

vlc is a Qt 5 application.  According to [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wayland#Qt_5), to run any Qt application in `wayland` you need to install `qt5-wayland` or `qt6-wayland` and use the `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland` environment variable to accomodate for wayland applications.  For applications misbehaving in wayland, use `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=xcb` before running the application.

Comment: I got my apps to work by merely installing `qt5-wayland`. No need to set the variable.

Comment: For me, it was `qt6-wayland`.  Also set `QT_QPA_PLATFORM=wayland;xcb` if the application misbehaves in wayland

Comment: On Debian 12 it's `qtwayland5` or `qt6-wayland`.

Comment: On NixOS the required packages are available under `libsForQt5.qtwayland` and `qt6.qtwayland`.